# Performance difference between Byte.compare() and Equality check (i.e. ==) when comparing the value of 2 primitive bytes in Java

Tags: java, byte

What is the difference between these two cases? Would the equality check be wrong? If not, which one is faster?

Comment: You understand the difference between a primitive value (non-object) and an object instance?

Comment: It's the basic understanding of OOPL in general, and JAVA in particular.

Comment: But where is performance discussed in the "duplicated" one?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen @Joe I'm not sure what this has to do with anything, since `Byte.compare` (and any other `<PrimitiveWrapperClas>.compare` method) is `static` and should be invoked with primitive types as arguments.

Answer (score -1):

If you use wrapper class (Byte instead of byte), you should use equals method. The code below doesn't work (not likely to happen) as == compare reference not the value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Byte b1 = new Byte((byte) 0);
    Byte b2 = new Byte((byte) 0);
    System.out.println(b1 == b2);
}
```

Some explanation [here](https://javapapers.com/java/java-integer-cache/).